# looping a self made function with array of arguments and get array as result in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Having a function

```
def my_function (argument):
    summe=argument+5
    print(summe)
    return
```

I want to loop the function for different arguments like

```
arguments=linspace(-0.1,-8.0,80)
```

and every single sum (summe) to be saved in one array together

So how can I repeat a function (the simple function above is only an example) with different arguments?

result shoul look like:

```
[4.9,4.8,4.7 ... -2.8,-2.9,-3.0]
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear, at least to me. Could you [edit] your question with the result you'd like to get for this sample input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to `return` the sum from your function like this:

```
def my_function (argument):
    summe = argument + 5
    print(summe)
    return summe
```

Then, given that you have some arguments in an array, for example:

```
arguments = [-0.1,8.0,80]
```

You can loop over these arguments and store the result of your function calls in another array using a list comprehension:

```
result = [my_function(arg) for arg in arguments]
```